# Selecting Specific information from an API and console log that information in ReactNative

Tags: json, reactjs, api, react-native

I'm currently working in reactNative and based on the user's location (latitude and longitude) I am trying to find postcodes that are around that given location. Using the API i can easily convert the postcode and get back a json response with different objects, each object corresponding with a postcode. From that Information I only want to extract the 'postcode' field. This is what I have done so far but I'm getting errors:

```
const [parkingPostcode,setparkingPostode] = useState([])
//In here I store the information

const searchPostcode = async() => {

        const response2 = await postcodes.get("",{

            params:{
                longitude: userLongitude,
                latitude : userLatitude,
                limit: 10

            }

        })
        console.log(response2.data)
        setparkingPostode(response2.data)
// This is where I make the API call and everything works as expected

      }


//Below is the function I want to use to display the postcodes which are around the user:
      {parkingPostcode.map((val, index) => {
          key={index}
          console.log(val.postcode) 
        })}
```

When I try to run this, I am getting the following error:
"[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...parkingPostcode.map...')]"

This is the full code

```
import React ,{Component,useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import {View,Text,StyleSheet,Dimensions,Button,Alert,FlatList,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import MapView , {Marker}from 'react-native-maps'
import axios from 'axios'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import camdenParking from '../api/camdenParking'
import postcodes from '../api/postcodes'
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar'





const HomeScreen = ({navigation})=>

{

    const [parkingSpaces,setparkingSpaces] = useState([])
    const [parkingPostcode,setparkingPostcode] = useState([])
    const[term,setTerm] = useState('')
    let userLatitude = 0
    let userLongitude = 0 


      const searchApi = async() => {

        const response = await camdenParking.get("",{

            params:{

                postcode: term


            }

        }) // you can change this later on
        console.log(response.data)
        setparkingSpaces(response.data)
        console.log(term)      
      }





      const searchPostcode = async() => {

        const response2 = await postcodes.get("",{

            params:{
                longitude: userLongitude,
                latitude : userLatitude,
                limit: 10

            }

        }) // you can change this later on
        console.log(response2.data)
        setparkingPostcode(response2.data)

      }


      const showPostcode =() => {

        {parkingPostcode && parkingPostcode.map((val, index) => {
          key={index}
          console.log(val.postcode) 
         })}

       }





















      const findCoordinates = () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          position => {
            const locationString = JSON.stringify(position); // Here we get the JSON object but it needs to be parsed
            var longLat = JSON.parse(locationString); // Here we parse the JSON object

             userLatitude=longLat.coords.latitude
             userLongitude=longLat.coords.longitude

             console.log(userLatitude) // This prints the current latitude from the user
             console.log(userLongitude) // This prints the longitude



          },
          error => Alert.alert(error.message),
          { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
        );
      };






    return(


        <View style={styles.container}>
            <SearchBar 
                term={term}
                onTermChange={newTerm=>setTerm(newTerm)}
                onTermSubmit={()=> searchApi(term)}
                />
            <MapView
                style={styles.mapStyle}
                initialRegion={{
                latitude: 51.539190,
                longitude: -0.142500,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0122,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                }}
                >
                {parkingSpaces.map((val, index) => {
                return (<MapView.Marker
                        coordinate={{
                        latitude: parseFloat(val.latitude),
                        longitude:parseFloat(val.longitude)
                        }}
                        key={index}


                        >
                      <MapView.Callout tooltip style={styles.customView}>
                          <View style={styles.ParkingPopUpStyle}>
                              <Text style = {styles.parkingPopUpText}>

                                Restrictions: {val.restriction_type}{"\n"}{"\n"}
                                Maximum Stay: {val.maximum_stay}{"\n"}{"\n"}
                                Tariff : {val.tariff}{"\n"}{"\n"}
                                Operating Hours: {val.times_of_operation}{"\n"}{"\n"}
                                Nearest Pay Machine: {val.nearest_machine}{"\n"}{"\n"}
                                Parking Bay Length: {val.parking_bay_length_metres} {'Metres'}{"\n"}{"\n"}
                                Parking Permit Required To Park For Free: {val.controlled_parking_zone}{"\n"}{"\n"}


                              </Text>
                          </View>
                      </MapView.Callout>
                    </MapView.Marker>

                        ); 






                })}

            </MapView>


            <Button style={{ borderWidth: 2, alignItems:'right',justifyContent:'right'}} title="Info" onPress={() => console.log("This is not fired")}/>


            <Button onPress={searchApi} title=" Click Here To Get Parking Spaces" />
            <Button onPress={findCoordinates} title=" Click Here To Get User's Location" />
            <Button onPress={searchPostcode} title=" Click Here To Get Near Postcodes" />
            <Button onPress={showPostcode} title=" Display Postcode" />

            <Text style={styles.bottomText}>{parkingSpaces.length} Parking Spaces found around {term}</Text>

            <Text>
              NW6 5HZ {"\n"}
              NW1 0XF {"\n"}
              NW1 1QE {"\n"}
              NW6 1NB {"\n"}



            </Text>


        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
    {
     container:{
         flex:1,
         backgroundColor: '#fff',
         //alignItems: 'center',
         //justifyContent: 'center',
         //...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
         //marginLeft:0,
         //height:400,
         //width:400,
         //justifyContent:"flex-end",
         //alignItems:"center",   
     },

     mapStyle: {
        width: 400,
        height:400, 
        //width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        //height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
      },

      ParkingPopUpStyle:{
        backgroundColor:'#CECECE',
        borderWidth:0, //1
        width: 375,
        height:300,
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent:'space-between'

    },
    bottomText:{

      textAlign:'center'
    },
    parkingPopUpText:{
      fontSize: 16,
      marginLeft:10,
      marginTop:7,

    }

    }

)

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: You expect `parkingPostcode` to be an array. Are you sure `response2.data` is an array?

Comment: yes, this is the response2.data : prnt.sc/r08xyy

Comment: It seems to be a string to me. This error happened because `parkingPostcode` does not respond to the method `map`. Can you tell me what `console.log(response2.data.constructor.name)` yields?

Comment: this is what it yields: Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `setparkingPostcode(response2.data.result)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure `console.log(response2.data)` logs the correct output?
2. `searchPostcode` is an async function, which means you have no idea when that function will finish its execution and update your state.

Which means this piece of code

```
{parkingPostcode.map((val, index) => {
    key={index}
    console.log(val.postcode) 
})}
```

is executed way before `searchPostcode` finishes, therefore you don't have any results.

3. This piece of code

   ```
   {parkingPostcode.map((val, index) => {
        key={index}
        console.log(val.postcode) 
   })}
   ```

is supposed to loop through an array and for each element return something, which it doesn't, it just gives a variable called `key` (a variable which is not defined in anywhere in your code) a value of `index` and then it doesn't return anything.

Anyways, this should not fail because `parkingPostcode` is initalized as an empty array, so looping through an empty array should not fail.

Based on you error, most likely the API call fails and you don't have a catch block to handle the failing case, so wrapping all your API call related code inside a `try-catch` should get rid of the error.

You have to fix the rest of the code in order to handle this cases.

Comment: So you are suggesting that the function should not be async? And yes, i'm sure that the response2.data logs the correct output

Comment: And something else I just noticed now. Where is your `searchPostcode` function actually being called? From you code, the function never gets called.

Comment: This is proof that the api search works: https://prnt.sc/r08xyy

Comment: Based on your screenshot, you have a `result` object there. `postcode` is inside a `result` object. I never see you accessing `result.postcode`

Comment: Sorry, I'm just learning this new programming language. Could you tell me how to access result.postcode and where to access it?